# How to trigger a button as clicked using jquery or jscript?

Tags: asp.net, javascript, jquery

Is there a way to trigger a hidden button on an html markup page using jquery or jscript?

How would I do that if possible?

Thank you,

James

Answer (score 5, accepted):

With jQuery:

```
$('#buttonId').click();
```

or:

```
$('#buttonId').trigger('click');
```

With plain JavaScript:

```
document.getElementById('buttonId').onclick();
```

Since you're using ASP .NET you might want to get the button id by using the ClientID server-side property of the control:

```
$('#<%=Button.ClientID %>').click();
```

Or:

```
document.getElementById('<%=Button.ClientID %>').onclick();
```

Comment: I went with this one: $('#<%=Button.ClientID %>').click();

Thank you

Answer (score 2):

```
$('#example-button-id').click();
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you want to fire an event programmatically.  This is usually not necessary.  You can very easily move the button click even code to a new method, and have the event invoke that method.  You can then also call the method in the code that would want to fire the button click even programmatically.

Answer (score 0):

Try this (requires jquery):

```
$("button").trigger('click');
```